# Apply if statement groupby pandas dataframe. The truth value of a Series is ambiguous error

Tags: python, pandas

I can not apply an if statement on the column difference_bearing.
If the values of the column difference_bearing(float) > 20. The expected result would be -1. In all other cases the expected results would be 0.

```
df_FCD_big.groupby(['tripID'])['difference_bearing'].apply(lambda x: -1 if x >20 else 0)
```

The following warning pops up.

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Thanks in advance

Comment: GroupBy is not required: `df['result'] = np.where(df['difference_bearing'] > 20, -1, 0)`

Comment: It is required in this case,  there are different groups (tripIDs). I am interested in the difference_bearing within a group not between a group.

Comment: I don't understand. Perhaps it would help to provide a [mcve] with sample data and output. Would really really go a long way towards making this question answerable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how you can overcome your error:

```
df_FCD_big.groupby(['tripID'])['difference_bearing'].apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: -1 if y > 20 else 0))
```

Comment: I still don't understand what the question (or answer) is trying to achieve. And suggesting nested apply as a solution for anything is a damned sin :-(

Comment: Yeah you are right. But I figured it out now. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @coldspeed.
If you need to know metrics within groups, you can do so by applying groupby after that, which would be lot more efficient.

```
df['result'] = np.where(df['difference_bearing'] > 20, -1, 0)
df_FCD_big.groupby(['tripID'])['result'].apply(sum)
```